# multiple models in one view (form view inside form view) - odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I have 3 models representing 3 levels of data but when viewing these models it has to be one view

models are "Group Match", "Match" and "Match Details", group match is like a small league which has number of matches and each match has its details, group match and match has to be form views not tree in form

So I need to view all of these 3 models in one view (may be nested view)

note: group match has field one2many to match and match has one2many field to match details

Answer (score 0):

you may want to use KanBan view for One2many

[image]

This way you can see all the informations in one form it needs a lot of coding ^^

Comment: Thanks for your effort, but actually I want to make it form view inside form view

Comment: you cant because when you click on save it will save two records like this my fiend has the same problem but form inside a form will save two records in the same time just to let you know